# LLDB - Qt missing debug info

Tags: c++, macos, qt, debugging, lldb

I've installed Qt 5.10.0 through the macOS installer.
I'm currently running OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.

Whenever I try to load any of the Qt libraries/ frameworks, I get the following warning:

```
warning: (x86_64) /Users/randomuser/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgets empty dSYM file detected, dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info.
```

I can reproduce the warning simply by running `lldb QtWidgets.framework`

I've tried setting DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX=_debug, but that doesn't seem to work.

Also, running `otool -L QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets_debug` reports the library being linked to the release versions of QtCore and QtGui.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit:
To elaborate on my attempt to use DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX, I tried the following, but it still resulted in the warning above.

```
export DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX=_debug
lldb
>env DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX=_debug
>target create QtWidgets.framework
>warning: (x86_64) /Users/randomuser/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgets empty dSYM file detected, dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info.
>Current executable set to 'QtWidgets.framework' (x86_64).
```

Comment: This usually happens when the build process builds a dSYM AFTER stripping the binary whose dSYM it is building.  The command "image list QTWidgets" will show the path to the dSYM it found.  You can use the "dwarfdump" tool from Terminal to look at the dSYM, but I would be surprised if it didn't also say it was empty.  But it sounds like you need to contact whoever is making up the distribution you have and get them to build the dSYM properly.

Comment: I found the dSYM package and it does contain a _debug version with all the necessary symbols. If I run `lldb QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets_debug` it finds the correct debug symbols for this library, but it loads the release versions of its dependencies instead of the debug ones (`QtCore` and `QtGui` instead of `QtCore_debug` and `QtGui_debug`). It appears like all the files are where they should be, but I can't get lldb to load the debug versions.

Comment: You are supposed to use the DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX environment variable to get dyld to load the other variants of a library.  Look at "man dyld" for more info on that.  You can set this in the environment you pass to the process you are launching either using the lldb `env` command, or in Xcode by setting it in the "Run" scheme of your project.

Comment: I made an edit to include more info about my attempt at using DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX.

Comment: Sorry I missed the comment about DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX in the original description.  Note, lldb doesn't do an exhaustive job of figuring out what the system would actually load before running.  Among other things it doesn't emulate the effect of DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX.  It doesn't get all the RPATH trickery right either.  At some point that's an effort with diminishing returns since everything will get sorted out when you run. So it is not surprising that your second experiment didn't work.

Comment: When you actually run a binary that loads the QT libraries, does that find the right binary with DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX set?  If it doesn't, did it find other _debug variants (for instance, there's a CoreFoundation_debug, and a libsystem_c_debug.dylib?  That would tell you whether it's just the QT library that's not getting loaded correctly, or whether the whole setting is not working for you somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Qt5.10.0

```
qmake CONFIG+=debug
make
lldb ./debug/qt_test.app/Contents/MacOS/qt_test
(lldb) env DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX=_debug
(lldb) image list
...
[ 16] 9A8C46A9-CADB-3DC2-9D5A-E04826477DCB 0x0000000000000000 /Users/macmini/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
 /Users/macmini/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/QtWidgets
...
```

dSYM seems to be loaded, but not for the _debug version of Qt libs. But when I run the application in lldb:

```
(lldb) b main
(lldb) r
... lldb breaks on main()...
(lldb) image list
...
[  9] 1292D5A0-4ADF-37C3-A724-DDB9B199EE8A 0x0000000100296000 /Users/macmini/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets_debug 
      /Users/macmini/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/QtWidgets_debug
...
```

Now it uses the _debug Qt libs with correct symbols.
Happy debugging!

Comment: I can confirm that the correct versions get loaded after running. Thank you!